# Speeding up parties substring checking

Tags: node.js, algorithm

Imagine an object with strings as keys and their frequency count of occurrence as the value.

```
{"bravo charlie": 10, "alpha bravo charlie": 10, "delta echo foxtrot": 15, "delta echo": 7}
```

I am trying to optimize an algorithm such that A) any key that is a substring of another key AND has the same frequency value should be eliminated. The longer containing key should remain. B) Allow keys that are only a single word to remain even if contained by another key

The following pairwise comparison approach works but becomes very very slow on large objects. For example, an object with 560k keys is taking ~30 mins to complete the pairwise comparison:

```
// for every multi word key
// if a part of a longer key in candidates AND have same length delete
let keys = Object.keys(candidates)
    .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
    .filter(key => {
        if (key.split(" ").length === 1) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    });
    // ^ order keys by length to speed up comparisons and filter out single words

    checkKeyI: for (const keyi of keys) {

        checkKeyJ: for (const keyj of keys) {

            // because we pre-sorted if length is less then we are done with possible matches
            if (keyj.length <= keyi.length) {
                continue checkKeyI
            }

            // keys must not match exactly
            if (keyj === keyi) {
                continue checkKeyJ
            }

            // keyi must be a substring of keyj
            if (!keyj.includes(keyi)) {
                continue checkKeyJ
            }

            // they must have the same freq occurr values
            if (candidates[keyj] === candidates[keyi]) {
                delete candidates[keyi]
                continue checkKeyI
            }

        }
    }
```

The desired result would be:

```
{"alpha bravo charlie": 10, "delta echo foxtrot": 15, "delta echo": 7}
```

because `bravo charlie` was eliminated. Are they any obvious or clever ways to speed this up?

Comment: If you did the loops by index you could start `j` at `i + 1`, and the first two conditions go away (although the second one was already unnecessary because of the length check). Also in `filter` just return `!key.includes(" ")`

Comment: Alternatively you could write a native module in C++ since this is Node.js

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the keys based on their length (use alphabetical ordering as a tie-breaker)
2. Starting with the longest key (and going in a descending order of length), add the keys to a trie. The leaf node for the key will store the value.
3. For inserting a key, start traversing the [trie](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/). If the key has a single word, insert it. If it has multiple words, and a match is found with the same frequency, don't insert it.

This will reduce your complexity from `O(n^2)` to `O(n*m)`, where `n = number of strings` and `m = length of longest string`

Comment: I like this. Thank you.  Would this only look for substrings that occur at the beginning of the key and not ones that occur in the middle?

Perhaps I split each key at the word level rotate through the array and insert each variant in the trie?  I.e.  "a b c" I would insert "a b c", "b c a", and "c a b" such that a later search for "b c" would thus be found?  Or am I missing something?